# Searching and replacing a windows style path using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

My task is to replace multiple entries for `\\\\\\\\server\\\path1\\\\path2\\\\ with \\\\server\\path1\\path2\\` in `myfile.txt`  (removing the superfluous backslashes).

I have tried using sed for this but it found nothing to replace:

```
sed 's:\\\\server\\path1\\path2\\:\\server\path1\path2\:g' myfile.txt
```

I also tried to escape the backslashes but it also found nothing to replace:

```
sed 's:\\\\\\\\server\\\\path1\\\\path2\\\\:\\\\server\\path1\\path2\\:g' myfile.txt
```

This may be a lame question but I'm really stuck with it. I've tried searching all over for a way to do this via a command but nothing I try works.

Comment: Just hazarding this, but is it possible you could just use: `sed 's/\\\\/\\/g' `

Comment: Which backslashes are superfluous? Will there only be one server string to replace or many? Can there be other backslashes in the file that shouldn't be changed? Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sed -e 's,\\\\,\\,g' -e 's/^\\\([^\\]\)/\\\\\1/'
```

(the 2nd part ensure that `\something` becomes `\\something` ... you may want that, or not, depending on what your use cases are)

That way:

```
\\something\already\ok   stays ok  (thanks to the 2nd part)
\\\\something\\like\\this becomes \\something\like\this
```

If you omit the 2nd part,

```
\\something\like\that becomes \something\like\that , which is wrong
```